# How to create a subclass with different default values that can still be changed?

Tags: python, class, animation, subclass

I would like to create a subclass of the `Text` class in this animation library I am using. I would like this subclass to have a different default font size, color, opacity, and stroke width than the `Text` parent class. I managed to make this work, but it is very verbose:

```py
class Explanation(Text):
  def __init__(self, text, fill_opacity=.6, stroke_width=1, *, color=ORANGE, font_size=60,
               line_spacing=- 1, font='', slant='NORMAL', weight='NORMAL', t2c=None, t2f=None,
               t2g=None, t2s=None, t2w=None, gradient=None, tab_width=4, height=None, width=None,
               should_center=True, unpack_groups=True, disable_ligatures=False, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(text, fill_opacity=fill_opacity, stroke_width=stroke_width, color=color, font_size=font_size,
               line_spacing=- line_spacing, font=font, slant=slant, weight=weight, t2c=t2c, t2f=t2f,
               t2g=t2g, t2s=t2s, t2w=t2w, gradient=gradient, tab_width=tab_width, height=height, width=width,
               should_center=should_center, unpack_groups=unpack_groups, disable_ligatures=disable_ligatures, **kwargs)
```

Now this works, but it seems like a lot of code just to change the default value of 4 arguments. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Don't duplicate the keyword-only arguments whose defaults you aren't changing. They can be gathered by `kwargs` and passed to the parent.

```
class Explanation(Text):
    def __init__(self, text, fill_opacity=.6, stroke_width=1, *, color=ORANGE, font_size=60, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(text, fill_opacity=fill_opacity, stroke_width=stroke_width, color=color, font_size=font_size, **kwargs)
```

(Note that `line_spacing=- 1` is just setting the default to -1; it's a bug in the code generating the documents. `=-` is not a special assignment operator.)